# ES6 js keywords as param exact behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a code which is expected to return 'undefined' or any error but it gives output as mentioned.

```js
let i = (x, c) => {
    c(x);
};

i(20, (undefined) => {
    let j = undefined;
    console.log(j);
});


function y(undefined) {
    let a = undefined;
    console.log(a);
}
y(90);
```

How reserved words works and change behavior if used in function arguments?

Comment: I'm always curious why some people are so curious about programming constructs that you should NEVER EVER use.  Nothing good comes from writing code this way.  At best, it makes confusing code to understand.  At worst, it's so hard to understand that you mess up the way the code works or someone else trying to work on your code gets things wrong.  I'd say spend more time understanding good ways to code, not bad ways to code.

Comment: @jfriend00 perhaps an homework or something similar? These are the kind of questions some of my friends actually happens to have at university tests / practices. I perfectly agree that, however, nothing good comes from such a way of programming, other than discovering that undefined actually isn't (surprisingly?..) a reserved word in javascript.

Comment: IMO, if this is homework, any course that is spending time teaching about this is missing an opportunity to teach something a lot more important and useful.  It's a cute little corner of the language that should probably never be used.

Comment: @jfriend00 I perfectly agree with you. However, in my little study life (I didn't study just that much), I've met several teachers / courses where the goal was not exactly teaching useful informations and sometimes, in my opinions, the teacher was just not enough competent to teach the correct informations, giving misleading examples that actually didn't help at all learning. In a nutshell, I actually can imagine a situation where this task was given to "wrongly" explain a concept that, for instance, could be about reserved words in javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`undefined` is not a reserved word.

It is a global, readonly variable.

Nothing stops you defining another variable with the same name in a narrower scope.

Answer (score 3):

`undefined` is **not** a reserved word, as you can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords.

In your scenario, `undefined` actually holds the callback value, which is 20 in the first case and 90 in the second one.

For instance, if you want to assign the value `undefined` to the scoped `j` or `a`, you can use `void 0`.
Further informations about how `void` works can be found here (also, `void` is actually a reserved word in javascript): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

```js
let i = (x, c) => {
    c(x);
};

i(20, (undefined) => {
    let j = void 0;
    console.log(j);
});


function y(undefined) {
    let a = void 0;
    console.log(a);
}
y(90);
```